# How to export 2 or more selected tracks as one

Tags: logic-pro

say I selected 2 tracks. Say I want export the resulting of the 2. How to?

I mean, say I want an aiff/wav/mp3/whatever of the guitar with the keys, or bass with drums. How to? It seems I can only export all together or the 2 separated. Can't really understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found how:

first > right click the track > configure track header > be sure the
   on/off button is visible.

second > deactivate the ones you don't want

third > file > bounce > project or section

Only the activated tracks will be merged and exported.